# regex which matches anything with at least a letter in parentheses

Tags: regex

I've managed to create a regex which matches anything between parentheses:

```
  \(([^\)]+)\)
```

… now I need a regex which will match anything with at least a letter in these parentheses

Comment: Matches and grabs? I suppose you require the match group?

Comment: `\((?=[a-zA-Z]+)([^\]+)\)` would do if your regex engine support lookahead [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nH8eT5/1)

Comment: @Tensibai that will **only** work if the _first_ character inside the parenthesis is a letter - `(1a)` will not match. [demo](http://regex101.com/r/dZ3qD8/1)

Comment: aw right, forgot that. this one would do `\((?=.*[a-zA-Z]+)([^\)]+)\)` [Updated demo](http://regex101.com/r/nH8eT5/2)

Comment: fails here http://regex101.com/r/nH8eT5/3. It would be `\((?=[^()]*[a-zA-Z]+)([^\)]+)\)` http://regex101.com/r/nH8eT5/4

Comment: @Tensibai all in all, the [non lookahead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25908323/2071828) solution is neater I think.

Comment: @boristhespider indeed, just commented

Answer (score 2):

You can just expand your regex and put the required letter in it with any characters around (those characters can use `*` as you the letter is already the required one character):

```
\(([^\)]*[a-zA-Z][^\)]*)\)
```

Comment: it works! great! Thanks! Why do we need the star sign?

Comment: @cwar05 You need `*` to allow any number of non-`)` characters. Only one letter is enforced, the rest of characters can be anything  except closing `)`.